# How to check length inside *ngIf with async pipe in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

How to check length inside `*ngIf` with async pipe?

I try to do this way, but its not working. what is the correct way to do it?

```html
<mat-menu #favoriteMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-container *ngIf="items$ | async as items && items.length; else empty">
    <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      ...
    </button>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #empty>no favorite here</ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the best solution still is, to split this up into 2 containers. That is not pretty, but AFAIK the only solution to do what you want to achieve while avoiding duplicate subscriptions to the `Observable`.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="items$ | async as items; else empty">
  <ng-container *ngIf="items?.length > 0; else empty">
     ...
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #empty>no favorite here</ng-template>
```

Comment: I think its create code that hard to follow. I looking for "one line solution". and what the first `if` is false? I'll not get the empty message..

Comment: I don't think there is a one line solution ;) you can rearrange the code to still show the empty template also when first if is false

Comment: I updated the code, so you also receive the empty message when first if is false

Comment: This is the best solution you can get Jon Sud, you can not expect to have a solution which does not exist

Answer (score 2):

With a slight modification to the observable you can achieve this.

For example:

```js
items$: Observable<number[] | undefined> = of([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(map((items) => {
    if(items?.length > 0) {
      return items;
    }
    return undefined;
  }));
```

Here you need to use the pipe and map function additionally. Then in the template file:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(items$ | async); else empty; let items">
  <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{item}}
  </button>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #empty>no favorite here</ng-template>
```

Using this way only one subscription is created also it fallbacks to empty template if the array is empty. Hope this would help you. You can find the stackblitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qt4t9v?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score -2):

Why container? True. In this case, there is not much difference. (https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

```html
<ng-template *ngIf="(items$ | async).length > 0">
   <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
      {{ item }}
   </button>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: keep in mind that this creates 2 subscriptions to `items$`